# Express Survival Probability in terms of Accumulated Hazard for discrete random variable

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, hazard

I want to find a way to express $\Pr(X \ge x)$ as a function of accumulated hazard $H(x)=\int_0^x h(u)du$.  $h$ is the hazard function, usually defined as $h(x)=f(x)/(1-F(X))$, which $f$ and $F$ are the pdf and cdf of $X$.

Hazard functions are typically used in time-to-event settings where a nonnegative and continuous random variable $X$ measures the time until a random event.  The event might be time until a person's death, for example, and the hazard function $h$ would represent the instantaneous risk as a function of time.

I'm interesting in the relationship between $h$ and the survival function $ S(x) = \Pr(X \ge x) $.  For the continuous case it works out this way.

### Continuous Case

$$
\begin{align}
h(x) &= \lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}
\frac{ \Pr(x<X<x+\Delta x \mid X \ge  x)}{\Delta x} \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}
\frac{S(x)-S(x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x  S(x)} \\
&= \frac{-S^\prime (x)}{S(x)} \\
&= -\frac{d}{dx}\log S(x)
\end{align}
$$

Letting $H(x)=\int_0^x h(u)du $ represent the accumulated hazard, that last equality gives,
$$
S(x) = e^{-H(x)}
$$

### Discrete Case

I want to find the analogous expression for the discrete case.  Here we can imagine making observations during discrete epochs, each of which has a probability to hold an event.  $X$ counts the number of epochs (e.g., days) the elapse before the event.  Now $h(k)$ is simply the probability of an event on day $k$ given that no event occurred prior.

$$
\begin{align}
h(k) &= \Pr(X=k \mid X\ge k) \\
&= \frac{\Pr(X \ge k) - \Pr(X\ge k+1)}{\Pr(X\ge k)} \\
&= \frac{S(k)-S(k+1)}{S(k)} \\
&= \frac{-\Delta S(k)}{S(k)}
\end{align}
$$

Up to here the relationship between the survival probability $S$ and hazard $h$ is analogous to the continuous case.  I would like to carry the analogy farther and express $S$ in terms of the accumulated hazard $H(k) = \sum_{i=1}^k h(i)$.  Does anyone know how to do that?  That is, can you  find $\phi$ such that, for the discrete case,
$$
S(k) = \phi(H(k))
$$

---

Well, the answer I'm looking for is (sort of) stated in a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143377).

An inductive argument on the probabilities gives a product instead of an exponentiated integral:

$$
S(k) = \prod_{i=1}^k (1-h(i))
$$

I'm still curious to about a mathematical technique to fill in the gaps:

$$
\begin{align}
h(k) &= -\frac{\Delta S(k)}{S(k)} \\
&\vdots \\ &? \\
&\vdots \\
S(k) &= \prod_{i=1}^k (1-h(i)) \\
&= e^{\sum_{i=1}^k \log(1-h(i))} \\
&\approx e^{-\sum_{i=1}^k h(i)} \qquad \text{(for h values small)} \\
&= e^{-H(k)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The discrete and continuous cases are united in a single (integral) formula simply by interpreting the integral in the sense of [Lebesgue-Stieltjes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration)